# Binary Search Tree Question on Recursive Storage

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

Since it's a recursive method, I can't figure out how to use these stg arguments to store the tree element data. 
I want to keep the stg there so I can learn how to store that string data in a recursive method. How do I do this?(basically i want to get rid of the temp1)

Edit: I tried stg += root.getElement() + " "; with return stg; and it did not work

System.out.println("inOrder traversal of tree: " + inOrder(root, ""));

static String temp1 = "";

```
public static String inOrder(BinaryTreeNode<String> root, String stg) {
    if (root != null) {

        // recur to left side
        inOrder(root.getLeft(), stg);

        // print the tree element
        temp1 += root.getElement() + " ";

        // recur to right side
        inOrder(root.getRight(), stg);

    }
    stg = temp1;

    return temp1;
} // inOrder
```

Output example "inOrder traversal of tree: 1 2 3 X Y Z x y z"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `stg` argument. You just need to concat the left side, then the current element, and then the right side:

```
public static String inOrder(BinaryTreeNode<String> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return "";
    }

    return inOrder(root.getLeft()) + root.getElement() + inOrder(root.getRight());
}
```